# Is there a way to alias field names in salesforce outbound messages?

Tags: soap, wsdl, salesforce

I have a number of outbound messages for different fields in salesforce, the fields are nearly all identical except for the name.  Right now I have different web services handling the call for each field; to ease processing on the message receiver I would like to have one service handling all the different fields.

Each receiving web service uses a separate WSDL for each outbound message.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you consolidate the outbound messages into a single outbound message?  If that's not an option, you could make your endpoint smarter by having it introspect the SOAP message salesforce sends and then delegating the request to one of many different handlers (one for each different WSDL).  But that would be a good bit of work.